# Universal reference deduction using the same_as concept

Tags: c++, reference, constraints, c++-concepts, forwarding-reference

I'm trying to implement a push function for a blocking queue which accepts a universal reference as it's template parameter, but requires that the template argument be the same type as the queue's element type:

```
template <typename ValueType>
class shared_queue
{
public:
    template <typename Arg>
        requires std::same_as<Arg, ValueType>
    void push(Arg&& arg);
private:
    std::deque<ValueType> container_;
};
```

However, I'm not quite sure how is universal reference deduction supposed to work in this case, or if it works at all for that matter. The following code:

```
shared_queue<int> sq;
int x{ 5 };
sq.push(x); // won't compile
sq.push(5); // all good
```

does not compile. The compiler complains that:
[image: Compiler error, constraints not satisfied]

I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding something but I don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `remove_reference` from `Arg` for `same_as` to consider the `int&` to `x` and `int` the same type. You may also want to remove `const` in case you have `const int x` and pass that as a parameter. Removing both (+ `volatile`) can be done with `std::remove_cvref_t`:

```cpp
template <typename Arg>
    requires std::same_as<std::remove_cvref_t<Arg>, ValueType>
void push(Arg&& arg) {
    container_.push_back(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
}
```

Another option would be to allow for *any* arguments that can be used to construct a `ValueType`:

```cpp
template <class... Args>
    requires std::constructible_from<ValueType, Args...>
void emplace(Args&&... args) {
    container_.emplace(container_.end(), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the remove_reference option is exactly what I was looking for. I'll look into universal references a bit more.